# I am using Genetic Algorithm to solve a maze but it doesn't seem to work and was wondering if someone could point out the mistake I have done(python)

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, maze

I am using a random maze generator and then trying to implement GA to it so it can solve it, I do get an output but it seems for each generation it either does worse or better but never really solving it, feels like I am missing something, would like some guidence! This is python.

Here is the policy:

```py
from random import shuffle, randrange
%pylab inline
import numpy
from pandas import *

def generateRandomPolicy(x,y):
    policy=numpy.random.random((x,y,4))
    for i in range(policy.shape[0]):
        for j in range(policy.shape[1]):
            policy[i][j]=policy[i][j]/policy[i][j].sum()
    return policy

def mutatePolicy(policy,my=0.01):
    newPolicy=policy
    for i in range(newPolicy.shape[0]):
        for j in range(newPolicy.shape[1]):
            mustNormalize=False
            for k in range(newPolicy.shape[2]):
                if numpy.random.random()<my:
                    newPolicy[i][j][k]=numpy.random.random()
                    mustNormalize=True
            if mustNormalize:
                newPolicy[i][j]=newPolicy[i][j]/newPolicy[i][j].sum()
    return newPolicy
mutatePolicy(generateRandomPolicy(1,1),my=0.1)
```

The fitness function (I am thinking it's here I have done wrong)

```
def fitnessFunction(organism,target):
    #target is the maze


    actions=list()
    
    while not maze.mazeSolved() and len(actions) < 5000:

        action=numpy.random.choice([0,1,2,3],p=policy[maze.xPos][maze.yPos])
        maze.moveAgent(action)
        actions.append(action)
        
    maze.resetAgent()  
    
    return 1.0/(1.0+len(actions))
```

Here we put in values and try it out

```
populationSize=10
mutationRate=0.01
generations=50
#generate population

population=list()
for n in range(populationSize):
    population.append(generateRandomPolicy(17,17))
    
maxW=[]
meanW=[]


for generation in range(generations):
    
    #evaluate fitness of each solution
    W=[]
    for organism in population:
        W.append(fitnessFunction(organism,maze))

    #selection for the next generation
    Wmax=max(W)
    nextPopulation=list()
    best=population[W.index(Wmax)]
    maxW.append(Wmax)
    meanW.append(mean(W))
    for n in range(populationSize):
        who=numpy.random.randint(populationSize)
        
        if n<2: #elite selection
            who=W.index(Wmax)
        else:
            #selection function Roulette:
            #while numpy.random.random()>W[who]/Wmax:
            #    who=numpy.random.randint(populationSize)
            #selection function Tournament:
            other=numpy.random.randint(populationSize)
            if W[other]>W[who]:
                who=other
            
        #inheritance and mutation
        nextPopulation.append(mutatePolicy(population[who],my=m)) #<-
        
    #updating the old to the new poplution
    population=nextPopulation
    #housekeeping
    #if (generation%100)==0:
    print(generation,1.0/Wmax)
        
#visualizing results
plot(maxW,'r')
plot(meanW,'k')
```

Comment: Your fitness function provides a very weak signal, since it's drowned in the noise introduced by the fact you measure the length of a single random attempt at solving using the policy. Maybe it's better if you take a large number of samples and average them, although I fear this may not be a problem that's well suited for a GA.

Comment: @PaulHankin I don't think I really understand what you mean, sorry could you explain it in a different way ?

Comment: Your fitness function makes a random path, sampled from the policy and stops when it reaches length 5000 or the maze is solved. It's value is essentially the inverse of this length. If you have two policies, one slightly better than the other, what's the chance that your fitness function says the better one is better than the worse one? Given the amount of randomness involved, (I believe) the answer is approximately 50%, so you're essentially picking random policies at each step.

Comment: My suggestion is to run the inner loop of the policy many times (perhaps 1000), producing lots of random solution paths and taking (the reciprocal of) their average length as the fitness value. This reduces the randomness in your function, and so decreases the noise.

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks a lot! I will look into that!